# Get Cell value from DataGrid

Tags: wpf, indexing, datagrid

I am having some troubles with my datagrid ( WPF ) and since I am already a beginner I am not so very good in it.

Maybe, someone can help me out here.

I already have the row-index and column index and what I want to have now is the value from this cell.
But I do not know how to get it.

Here is my code:

```
var row = datagrid.Items.IndexOf(datagrid.CurrentItem);
var column = datagrid.SelectedCells[0].Column.DisplayIndex;
```

How is it possible now to retrieve with these two indexes now my cell vlaue.

I must solve it somehow via the indexes!

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the sample code that gets cell value from datagrid in WPF on button click

In your **MainWindow.cs**

```
     private ObservableCollection<ItemDG> _it = new ObservableCollection<ItemDG>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _it.Add(new ItemDG() { Amount = 10 });
        _it.Add(new ItemDG() { Amount = 20 });
        _it.Add(new ItemDG() { Amount = 30 });

        dataGrid1.ItemsSource = _it;
    }

    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBlock x = dataGrid1.Columns[0].GetCellContent(dataGrid1.Items[2]) as TextBlock;
        if (x != null)
            MessageBox.Show(x.Text);
    }
}
public class ItemDG
{
    public int Amount { get; set; }
}
```

and in your **MainWindow.xaml**

```
 <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="datagrid1"/>
 <Button Content="Button" Name="button1" Click="button1_Click_1" />
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This solved my problem that I was thinking about for the last couple of hours! Thank you very much!